# can anybody explain me how the contains() method work in String class?

Tags: java

```
public boolean contains(CharSequence s) {
    return indexOf(s.toString()) > -1;
}
```

This is a predefined method in String class but I didn't understand the passing parameter `CharSequence s` and `indexOf(s.toString()) > -1`.

Would anyone explain me clearly please as I am new to java and mainly what the 
indexOf method will do in the return type.

Comment: Your best bet here is to get familiar with [the API documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/).

Comment: Indeed - when you don't understand what something will do, read the docs for it.

Answer (score 1):

`indexOf()` will return the index of a subString if it exists within the String it is called on or `-1`.

In this case, it will then be compared to -1 via `>`, which results in `true` or `false` which will then be returned.

Comment: Thank you #Dragondraik k

Answer (score 1):

[`CharSequence`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) is an interface, and so `String#contains` can accept anything that implements that interface. One of the classes that implements it is `String`, but there are others as well.

`CharSequence` defines a method, `toString`, which converts the character sequence to a `String`.

`String` defines an [`indexOf` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) that accepts a `String` substring and tells you whether it's in the string by returning the index at which it appears in the string. It returns -1 if the substring isn't in the string.

So `indexOf(s.toString()) > -1` tells you whether the string contains the substring defined by the `CharSequence` `s`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the name of the method says it all:
does String x contain String y, when `boolean z = x.contains(y);`

For a better explanation: just check here 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-

Answer (score 0):

The **indexOf** method return the first appeared position of the target string.
And returns -1 if it cannot find the match string.
So, if **indexOf** method returns -1, it means it find nothing match. Which lead to the result of false.